# redirect user if not logged in (Firebase/ Vanila JS)

Tags: javascript, firebase

Good night, I need help with a problem that I'm not able to solve, I have a site with the index, register and login page, my problem is that I want that when the user is logged out he is redirected to the registration page if no, it is redirected to index, but I'm not able to do this without generating an infinite loop, could someone help me?

[Meu código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB18v.png)

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

if (user) {
    var uid = user.uid;
    console.log("usuario conectado")
    
} else {
   window.location = 'register.html'
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the current location that the user currently is before doing redirect.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    var uid = user.uid;
    console.log("usuario conectado")
    
} else {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/login.html') return // user is in login page, skip.
  if (window.location.pathname !== '/register.html') {
    window.location = 'register.html'
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I put this initial code on the 3 pages so it generated infinite looping, I tried to use your code but it didn't work, it continued infinite looping, which solved my problem was to create a new js file and import the initial code only in index, but I wanted the code to stay in the main js

Comment: Are you using webpack or what? Could you provide the error message?

Comment: the friend's solution above worked when I went up to the host, thanks!